# How do you wrap text at a space in C++

Tags: c++, string, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a text wrapping function that will receive a string and an amount of characters to count over before wrapping. If possible, I would like to keep any words from being cut off by looking for the previous space and wrapping there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string textWrap(string str, int chars) {
string end = "\n";

int charTotal = str.length();
while (charTotal>0) {
    if (str.at(chars) == ' ') {
        str.replace(chars, 1, end);
    }
    else {
        str.replace(str.rfind(' ',chars), 1, end);
    }
    charTotal -= chars; 
}
return str;
}

int main()
{
    //function call
    cout << textWrap("I want to wrap this text after about 15 characters please.", 15);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question about your existing code?  Does it not work? If so, how does it fail?

Answer (score 3):

Use [std::string::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) in combination with the [std::string::rfind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind). Part of the code that replaces a space character right of the `location`*th* character is:

```
std::string textWrap(std::string str, int location) {
    // your other code
    int n = str.rfind(' ', location);
    if (n != std::string::npos) {
        str.at(n) = '\n';
    }
    // your other code
    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << textWrap("I want to wrap this text after about 15 characters please.", 15);
}
```

The output is:

> I want to wrap
>   this text after about 15 characters please.

Repeat for the remainder of the string.

Comment: Note that this will give the wrong results if you have a word which goes past the line length; you should probably check both against `std::string::npos` and the start of the line before doing the replace.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way than searching for spaces yourself:

```
Put the line into a `istringstream`. 
Make an empty `ostringstream`. 
Set the current line length to zero.
While you can read a word from the `istringstream` with `>>`
    If placing the word in the `ostringstream` will overflow the line (current line 
    length + word.size() > max length)
        Add an end of line `'\n'` to the `ostringstream`.
        set the current line length to zero.
    Add the word and a space to the `ostringstream`.
    increase the current line length by the size of the word.
return the string constructed by the `ostringstream`
```

There is one gotcha I'm leaving in there: Dealing with the final space on the end of the line.